# How can I find (and eliminate) all unreferenced fields declared in an interface?

Tags: java, code-analysis, codepro

After eliminating some specific nonsense pattern, I need to identify and possibly delete fields that are declared in some interface like this:

```
public interface X
{
    String A = "xxx";
    String B = "zzz";
}
```

Sure I can use Eclipse's "find all references" for one identifier after another, but facing thousands of them lets that appear like a very dull fulltime job for days to come.

I tried both Google CodePro and the warnings that the Java compiler can spit out on demand, but found only options for non-public fields in classes, not for public fields in interfaces.

My next try would be: Comment them all out, and go through the errorlist. All fields that are not in the error list can be safely (in my case!) removed. That will be a dull day, too, because instead of a list of all fields that *do* have active references I am looking for a list of all fields that are *not* referenced anywhere.

**So how can I find all those now-unreferenced fields efficiently?**

I mean: I see it is dangerous to look at those references for a given project because another project that my Eclipse workspace does not know about might have references. That might be the rationale behind not offering the warning/analysis option I look for in Eclipse or CodePro.

This is not the case here, though. If it's not references in my project, I want to eliminate it.

Comment: Note that interfaces can't have non-static fields.

Comment: You mean non-public fields? Yeah, good point. Maybe I should delete that aspect from the question.

Comment: Yes, any field defined in an interface is implicitly `public static final` and can't be defined otherwise. Thus there are no non-static, non-public or non-final fields.

Comment: What does it mean if my question received "close" votes -- that it is bogus?

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for repeating what I already suggested in my question :(

Comment: darn ... overlooked that paragraph somehow ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think UCDetector is what you want : http://www.ucdetector.org/

Comment: Works. Installation was a bit glitchy, though, but it does its job. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If IntelliJ IDEA is option for you, even free community edition will highlight unused interface methods on the spot

Comment: Thanks. I will stick to Eclipse, though.